# Share a custom TEXT status via facebook sdk

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I want to share a custom text status using facebook sdk in my android app.

I used [this facebook tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share)

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this)
                .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
                .build();
                uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

but how can I share text (not link)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using FacebookDialog (Facebook API) you cannot add message programmatically

Answer (score 1):

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

WebDialog feedDialog = (
    new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        params))
    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
            FacebookException error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // When the story is posted, echo the success
                // and the post Id.
                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                if (postId != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // User clicked the Cancel button
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                // User clicked the "x" button
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Publish cancelled", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Generic, ex: network error
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Error posting story", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    })
    .build();
feedDialog.show();
```

}

Comment: thank you, I try this and I get tons of errors, I am new to android programming, can u plz post a full code example?
@naveen-tamrakar

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
 private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForLink() {
            return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(mActivity)
            .setName(mTitle)
            .setDescription(mDescription)
            .setLink(mUrlShare);
        }
```

Comment: but this way is to share link too,, I want to share just TEXT :\

Comment: and where can I add the text?

Comment: if you want share only text, it's the way below ↓